# What is the solution to being raped?

Tags: zina, rape

I'm married and have 3 kids. My husband's behaviour was very bad with me always.  Because of his lack of attention and irritating nature, I started talking with my colleague.

I was talking to him only and didn't want to start any relationship with him. I was a girl with a very strong character.  One day I went to his home and he started touching me, and he removed my clothes.  I did not agree and was telling him no, but he did everything and I couldn't stop him. I was very upset as I don't want to do this kind of act. Still I'm talking to him but not in any sexual relationship between us now. Please tell me the solution.

I cant sleep in nights and this sin is making me upset. I don't want to do this but he raped me. God knows what was his intentions, but I don't want to keep such relationships. I was also helping him by lending money; just that his talk would give me some courage. Please suggest what to do, it seems now that his intentions in the first place were to rape me.

Comment: Voting to close as the question isn't entirely in English/Arabic. Too many words to understand the question.

Comment: yeah, @AmericanMuslim is quite true. "the question isn't entirely in English/Arabic. Too many words..."   Actually it could a large edition.

Comment: See also: "[Qur'an 24](http://quran.com/24/31)"

Comment: The unedited question didnt show that he raped you as you have stated that he forced you and you were denying  and would it not be sufficient to say that somehow  you were involved in that act as you are still talking to him after that worst act and you went to him so what you needed from his home, must make tawbah sincerely get closer to Allah Swt by prayers and stop keeping relation with him this is not the solution for your husband behaviour its making worse for your world and akhirah may Allah Swt guide you.

Comment: As written, this looks like a solicitation for personal advice rather than a practical and answerable question about the topic of Islam. Please note that this is not the sort of discussion we as a site are geared to handle (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/189/22)

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullah,
First of all sister the wrong step you had taken was to talk to your college in the first place, if a husband and wife are having fights there are many Qur'anic verses that could help you to strengthen your bond. And I am sorry to point out but you should know as an adult and married woman going to a strangers and non mahrims house is like a sheep going to a wolf's house. But since it was not to your want and he is to blame but not completely.

My conclusions :- You need to ask Allah the merciful and oft forgiving for forgiving what had been done. And stay away from any 'hint' of wrongness. And if you and your husband are still not doing well here'a dua to help you.:
If there is a disagreement between husband and wife recite the ayat 99 times and blow on a sweet dish for 3 days which should be eaten by both of them.

Ayah nunber 21 Surah Ar Rum
Tell me if you do not have a copy of Holy Qur'an

Answer (score -2):

recite al hamdulillah then darood e tunajinna 100 times standing and in wudu or ablution or after taking bath in clean state and after that do sajadah say al hamdulillah 3 times and then pray for ur husband and youself kids and dont forget to pray for ur parents.insha allah allah will answer ur dua sister.